# Pause and resume a text using "Text to speech" to android with Android Studio

Tags: android, kotlin

Any code that does the function of pausing and resuming a text using "TextToSpeech"? This for a mobile project that uses Android Studio, with Kotlin language. I have seen examples but they are not clear to me.

in my project on ReadingActivity I have a test array:

```
ClassMateApplication.getApp()?.myList = arrayListOf(
                                "Oración 1",
                                "Oración 2",
                                "Oración 3",
                                "Oración 4",
                                "Oración 5",
                                "Oración 6"
                            )
```

So, in this function "play", I try to pause and get the index, this in order to give play again and start where I paused:

```
fun play(inicio:Int){
        Log.v("FVFFGWEDWDWDQWARERDS555", ClassMateApplication.getApp()?.myList!!.size.toString())
        if(inicio == 0){
            for((index, oracion) in ClassMateApplication.getApp()?.myList!!.withIndex()){
                ClassMateApplication.getApp()?.textToSpeech?.speak(oracion, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_ADD, null)
                ClassMateApplication.getApp()?.sentenceCounter = index + 1
            }

            //imageViewPlayerPlay.setImageResource(R.drawable.play_one)
        }else{
            var myList2: MutableList<String> = ArrayList()

            for((index) in ClassMateApplication.getApp()?.myList!!.withIndex()){
                if(index >= ClassMateApplication.getApp()?.sentenceCounter!!.minus(1)){
                    myList2.add(ClassMateApplication.getApp()?.myList!![index])
                }
            }

            for((index, oracion) in myList2.withIndex()){
                ClassMateApplication.getApp()?.textToSpeech?.speak(oracion, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_ADD, null)
                ClassMateApplication.getApp()?.sentenceCounter = index + 1
            }

            //imageViewPlayerPlay.setImageResource(R.drawable.play_one)
        }
    }
```

next this function is called in tha function "speakText":this function pauses and reproduces the text, but when I play, it does not return where I paused and starts from the index 0 of the array.

```
fun speakText(){
    //if (textToSpeech.isSpeaking()){
    if (ClassMateApplication.getApp()?.textToSpeech!!.isSpeaking()){
        imageViewPlayerPlay.setImageResource(R.drawable.play_one)
        pause()
    }else{
        imageViewPlayerPlay.setImageResource(R.drawable.pause)
        if(ClassMateApplication.getApp()!!.sentenceCounter > 0){ //wait int
            play(ClassMateApplication.getApp()!!.sentenceCounter)
        } else{
            play(0)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you edit your post to include the relevant section(s) of code and what you've tried already?

Comment: yes, I already made the changes